# Android background's image errors: AAPT error file failed to compile

Tags: android, reactjs, native, aapt

I have a problems with background's images. I have the same width and height from the last React Native app, which works, but when I edit and paste new image, always I get error:
`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
> > Android resource compilation failed
> ERROR:/Users/samwieszkto/Desktop/cenzor/cenzor/cenzor/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/background.9.png: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.`

I check and its saved correctly like png(not jpg):
[image]

I tried saved images by another Photoshop and other app, but the same error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I've seen recommendations to copy the "main" files to "release" as well, but that didn't work for me.